# google colab dice el str el objeto no puede ser interpretado como entero

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy haciendo un programa el cual genera contraseñas aleatoriamente a partir de un ancho de banda que ingrese cualquier usuario

```
import random
import string

def crear_pass(n):

    allChars = list(string.ascii_letters) + list(string.digits) + list(string.punctuation)
    passphrase = []

    for i in range(n):
        tmp = random.choice(allChars)
        passphrase.append(tmp)
    
    res = "".join(passphrase)
    return res

n = input("Ingresa ancho de Password: ")
test = crear_pass(n)
try:
    print(test)
except:
    print("Debe ingresar el ancho del Password")
```

Este es mi código, pero cuando lo corro en Google Colab me dice que hay un error en la parte `for i range (n)` dice "str objeto no se puede interpretar como un entero"

Answer (score 0):

La instrucción `input` lee un string:

```
n = input("Ingresa ancho de Password: ")
```

Si quieres el valor entero correspondiente, tienes que convertirlo explicitamente:

```
n = int(input("Ingresa ancho de Password: "))
```

Con eso `n` es un entero y no un string.

Comment: graciasss me solucionaste mi problema